# UTF8 lithuanian characters unrecognized in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding

I have well known but quite difficult to sort out problem here. And yes I was searching on forum but those threads are old enough so I decided to create new post.
So I built a website using WP and included html FORM in one page. When user fills the form (in his/her language) the values of the fields' go into MySQL database table reg_form.

Everything works, the values are saved, BUT some characters (specific in that language) are not recognized. I tried a lot of different methods to solve this, but nothing can help.

The strangest thing is that if you look at WordPress tables you can find those specific characters are recognizable but not in reg_form table which I created.

I was trying to solve this problem and finally I decided to approach in somehow ridiculous way. I created NEW database, new tables, installed new wordpress, created new form etc.

**That‘s what I was doing:**

I used this suggestion first:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/08/31/solving-php-mysql-utf-8-issues/

Yes, my files are saved using UTF8 encoding (without BOM). Yes, meta tags are ok. Yes, the FORM uses accept-charset='UTF-8'. Yes, all tables in database use UTF8. Yes, server, database and tables collation is the same “utf8_general_ci”.

Then I tried to insert in my code this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);

mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);
```

Then I tried this suggestion
link here: *akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/*

Then I tried to set Apache's AddDefaultCharset in .htaccess file using this link here: *httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#AddDefaultCharset*

BUT… still the problem remains. I can’t see those specific characters properly – only weird hieroglyphic.

Comment: What about `mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");`? (BTW do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated)

Comment: $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'database')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

    //mysqli_set_charset("UTF8", $dbc);

    mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $query = "INSERT INTO reg_form (a, b, c, etc.);

Comment: I haven't noticed you use Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face has to do with a little specific detail in database character encoding settings and Wordpress.

While Wordpress has a general character encoding setting that normally takes care about database tables as well, it does not care about the default character encoding setting of the database those tables are in.

So when your plugin/code adds a database table your own, you need to take care about the encoding settings as well - because by default they will be the database default you create the table in, which most likely is latin-1 which does not work well for your language.

To set the default character set for the database (replace *"wpdb"* with your database name if it varies):

```
ALTER DATABASE wpdb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

To change the character set for your existing table *"reg_form"*:

```
ALTER TABLE reg_form CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

*Note:* Backup your database first.

Comment: yes, this what I understood already. thank you anyway. but the problem still the same - why do those settings not work properly for my own table(-s)?

Comment: @BaltasVilkas: Because when you create your own tables they will inherit the character set from the database unless you specify the encoding. Does your *reg_form* table and all text-columns therein have the UTF-8 character set?

Comment: Thank you M8R-1jmw5r. I will try this in few hours later.

Comment: For the general understanding I can recommend the following post: [WordPress Database Charset and Collation Configuration](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/wordpress-database-charset-and-collation-configuration/). It is also linked from this fine [wordpress technical installation checklist](http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Hakre/Technical_Installation).

Comment: Now I tried the first and then the second settings. Nothing changed. Actually, this is what it outputs when I query in my database (with command SHOW CREATE TABLE reg_form;):  CREATE TABLE `reg_form` (  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `first_name` char(50) NOT NULL, etc., PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: The creation of your table looks fine.

Comment: but why I we can't see the character set beside each column then?

Comment: another question: do I have to do those settings straight after installing and before creating any columns?

Comment: That depends, read the linked article it explains very exactly when things kick into action. If you're writing a Wordpress plugin and you add (one/more) additional table(s), create those with the correct character set.

Answer (score 1):

HOLLY SHIT!! FINALLY! : ))))))))

The problem was that I was using mysqli_ queries. Now I tried to change to mysql_ (notice the change!) queries and it worked!! Two weeks of haaaaard working and researches... Phew!

Now who can explain me properly the reasons of this phenomena? : ))

Comment: Can't be the reason. But anyway, to deal with UTF-8, basically you have to prepare from the get go. Only way I could get this to work reliably and in a reproduceable manner was setting *everything* MySQL-related to work with UTF-8: database, table **and** column collations - and - charsets set to utf8 and additionally `SET NAMES utf8` upon connecting. MySQL is terrible.